# How To Annotate A PDF in iPad

Tags: ios, pdf

I need to annotate a PDF in my application. Is there any API for PDF annotation in iPhone/iPad ? Any suggestions?

Comment: have you fond the solution?

Answer (score 2):

You can draw an existing PDF onto a new PDF graphics context and then add whatever you like. See the answer to a [similar question for iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2313008/annotate-pdf-within-iphone-sdk/6376756#6376756https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2313008/annotate-pdf-within-iphone-sdk/6376756#6376756).

Answer (score 2):

You could use the PoDoFo Library to add, read or delete the Annotations. But you will need to write your own viewer to display the pdf including the annotations.

I recently wrote a simple viewer for the iPad with the integration of the PoDoFo Library. You can find the very [simple sample code on GitHub](https://github.com/xil3f/podofo_iOS_sample). There you can work with Square and FreeText annotations.

Comment: have you added a way to annotate widget annotations?

Comment: No, I don't work on this project at the moment. I think it should be possible with podofo, but you'll need to spend a lot of time as this Annotation type is not implemented yet in podofo.

Answer (score 2):

I created an open source framework for PDF annotation in IOS in GitHub. It supports both iPhone and iPad. Please check it out [here](https://github.com/lazyprogram/LazyPDFKit).

Answer (score 1):

No there is none, but you can probably create an array of UITextViews, with a custom background, as stickies or something like that.

You can make a UITextView with a custom background like so:

```
UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame: window.frame];
    textView.text = @"Notes";
    UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame: textView.frame];
    imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"myImage.jpg"];
    [textView addSubview: imgView];
    [textView sendSubviewToBack: imgView];
    [window addSubview: textView];
```

And then you can set the position with:

```
textView.position = CGPointMake(xcoord, ycoord);
```

Comment: plz look at "iAnnotate","GoodReader" applications. seems it is usinng any PDF API for annotation i am looking for same API which can be used to implement word search, highlight, add notes, etc in PDF document.

Comment: @user: They didn't necessarily use an API. They could have done it themselves.