# PDF Annots on iOS with Quartz

Tags: ipad, ios, pdf

Hmm, spending a couple of days trying to get the PDF annotations on my iPad application.
I'm using the following code to get the annotations, and yes! it works :) 
But the rect value is completely different then the IOS rect values. 
I can't figure it out how to place UIButtons on the spot where the annotation supposed to be.
For example, i have an annotation in the top left corner of the pdf file.

My /Annots/Rect values are, 1208.93, 2266.28, 1232.93, 2290.28 (WHAT?!)

How can i translate the PDF /Annots /Rect values to iOS x an y coordinates?

```
CGPDFPageRef page = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(doc, i+1);

CGPDFDictionaryRef pageDictionary = CGPDFPageGetDictionary(page);

CGPDFArrayRef outputArray;
if(!CGPDFDictionaryGetArray(pageDictionary, "Annots", &outputArray)) {
    return;
.... .... ....}
```

Comment: did you find a solution ? I'd LOVE to know what you did as I need to do the same thing

Comment: which one are u using ?i meant which framework and how did you make this work?

Answer (score 1):

I think those coordinates are in the "default user coordinate space" of the PDF. You need to apply a transformation that sends them into screen coordinates. You can use `CGPDFPageGetDrawingTransform` to get such a transformation. Make sure you're using the same transformation for drawing the page and the annotations.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is the problem but the Quartz 2D Coordinate Systems begins at the bottom left.

See Quartz 2D Programming Guide's [Coordinate Systems](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_overview/dq_overview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH202-CJBBAEEC) for more information.

Ps. If you got it working, I would like to see the result code for annotating.

EDIT:

Just found this code (not tested):

```
// flip context so page is right way up
CGContextTranslateCTM(currentContext, 0, paperSize.size.height);
CGContextScaleCTM(currentContext, 1.0, -1.0);
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2313008/annotate-pdf-within-iphone-sdk)