# Adding annotation in Pdf

Tags: iphone, pdf

How can I add annotation to an existing pdf file?  I saw libHaru library.But it doesn't allow editing existing file. How can i overcome it?

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2313008/annotate-pdf-within-iphone-sdk/6376756#6376756

Answer (score 0):

After running into this issue recently, I had to piece together a few ideas to make it work.

A few questions:
What type of annotation are you doing?
Do you have a png file of the pdf?
What are you doing with the file after it is appended?

Hi-level:
Convert pdf to image file either programmatically or before adding to the bundle.
Have appending done and saved on another layer of the view (OpenGL as an example).
Merge/Combine the two image layers.
Draw new combined image pdf.

Comment: I have only .pdf file.I need to add comment and also highlight the some text in the pdf file. I am currently using webview to display the pdf file.