# Add an annotation on a pdf

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, core-graphics, quartz-graphics

I have to develop a iPad app which can view a PDF file and draw some predefined annotations on it dynamically. It's like http://plangrid.com/ do.

I went though WWDC videos, stackoverflow and some other blogs.

But could not find a way to add a controller bar on the PDF. And drag a annotation from it and drop on the PDF.

I have an idea about to view a PDF. I followed [ZoomingPDFViewer example](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/ZoomingPDFViewer/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010281).

Please advise me.

I'm using XCode 4 and iOS 4.3.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you found the following stackoverflow post:
[Annotate PDF within iPhone SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2313008/annotate-pdf-within-iphone-sdk)

The first answer shows how to add text to a pdf page at a given location. This should be helpful for your purposes.

Comment: thanx for mentioning the post. have to try on that. think it will help me to get some idea. will update you the result.