# Text underline and highlight in PDF rendering

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, pdf-generation

I am using the following [project](https://github.com/vfr/Reader) from git hub for PDF rendering, But i need to provide user with the feature of underlining the text and highlighting text in the PDF

But when i tried to use web view for PDF rendering that I was able to highlight text and not underline it

I have tried using CGPDFDocument for PDF rendering also but i am not able to get that feature for text highlight nor underline text

I need to achieve text underline and text highlighting in PDF rendering also extract the text

Any help would be appreciated

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not easy to make annotations in PDF using iOS, You can use [Quartz Framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/GraphicsImaging/Reference/QuartzCoreRefCollection/Introduction/Introduction.html) . you can get some reference from here

[add annotation to pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6914906/add-annotation-to-pdf)

[add an annotation on a pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10373982/add-an-annotation-on-a-pdf)

[annotate pdf within iphone sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2313008/annotate-pdf-within-iphone-sdk)

[annotation notes comments using quartz 2d in ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11505782/annotation-notes-comments-using-quartz-2d-in-ios)

Or you can check some libraries here

[pspdfkit](http://pspdfkit.com/)

[fastpdfkit](http://fastpdfkit.com/)

[html pdf viewer ios xcode project](http://codecanyon.net/item/html-pdf-viewer-ios-xcode-project/154673)

[pdftouch sdk for ios](http://www.binpress.com/app/pdftouch-sdk-for-ios/859)

[poppler](http://poppler.freedesktop.org/)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can easily solve that problem. Try this with:

```
let selections = pdfView.currentSelection?.selectionsByLine()

    guard let page = selections?.first?.pages.first else { return }

    selections?.forEach({ selection in

        let highlight = PDFAnnotation(bounds: selection.bounds(for: page), forType: .underline, withProperties: nil)
        highlight.endLineStyle = .square
        highlight.color = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(1)

        page.addAnnotation(highlight)
        pdfView.document?.write(toFile: "PDF File Path")
    })
```

You can also forType change to the type you want.
For example, highlight, underline, ink, etc.

Comment: Thanks for reply Anna! The question was asked in 2013 when we were not using swift! Anyways, your answer would be helpful for needy folks!