# PDF annotation highlight & search text

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

How to play with the PDF document in ios?

I have to perform some operations on the PDF document like - read the PDF document, Adding annotations to PDF, making  note on PDF, Search text in PDF, highlighting the text in PDF document.

How this can be achieved? Can anyone please suggest me a sdk or tutorial? (Except PDFKitten...)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create PDF Annotations in iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10888950/create-pdf-annotations-in-ios)

Comment: Try PDFKitten. No seriously. If your expecting an answer outside of that then you are expecting too much. And your question is far too broad, asking multiple questions within this 1 question. If you don't get what you need from PDFKitten then your far from achieving your goal. I'm not saying it's the best, but it's open source and available for you to dive in and see how they are doing text search, which in return should give you an idea on how to do it. PDF manipulation is far from trivial and not easy to do, it's not as simple as a single tutorial

Answer (score 0):

I know it is old question but since iOS11 you can use [PDFKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/pdfkit).