# Achieving FastPdfKit annotation

Tags: ios, ipad, pdf, annotations

I am working with a pdf viewer in iOS.
My requirement is adding notes to pdf.I tried the fastpdfkit trial version.In that i saw a class which named "FPKAnnotation".

Can it be utilised for my requirement ..If so how  can i add annotation into the pdf with tht class?

I want to add a note icon and to add text to the note image?How can i do so?

Answer (score 0):

[Annotate PDF within iPhone SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2313008/annotate-pdf-within-iphone-sdk)

^ that is a different way of doing it although if you want to stick with fastpdfkit

http://support.fastpdfkit.com/kb/how-to/multimedia-overlays
Thats a tutorial for annotations using fastpdfkit

:) Hope this helps :]

Answer (score 0):

> Can it be used for my requirement? If so how can I add annotation
>   into the pdf with that class?

No, you cannot. FastKitPDF is PDF reader tool, not a PDF generation tool.